# Simple Wordpress Loop result completely wrong and full of breaks and <p> elements

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I am trying to make a simple loop through my wordpress posts but when it comes to output the whole thing the loop puts it anywhere but not where I said, it should be. For example the loop adds breaks and

but they are not in my posts. I had this problem once but dont know anymore what i have done to get over this problem.

**MY LOOP:**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ($loop->have_posts()) {
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $content = the_content();
        $headline = get_post_meta($post_id, 'headline', true);
        $subtitle = get_post_meta($post_id, 'untertitel', true);
        $class = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'post_tag', $termsargs );
        $bgimage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );

        echo '<section class="section zutaten '.$class[0].'" style="background-image: url('.$bgimage.')">';
        echo '<article class="zutaten-beschreibung">';
        echo '<header>';
        echo '<h2><strong>'.$headline.'</strong></h2>';
        echo '<h3>'.$subtitle.'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="zutaten-beschreibung-content">';
        echo $content;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</header>';
        echo '</article>';
        echo '</section>';

    endwhile;
} else {
    echo __('Fehler!');
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

**RESULT:**

[image: result of loop]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to wordpress....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `the_content()` is printing the data. you should use `get_the_content()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can see what's going wrong here. The `echo $content;` line is printing improper HTML. I know this because you've said in your caption there are many `<p>` tags where they should not be; and you're not (visibly) printing any `<p>` tags in this block of code.

Investigate what this method is returning: `$content = the_content();` That should do the trick.

Comment: thx mate. i tried it before but nothing happened. now another error happens with echoing out the $class[0] variable. console says: "Catchable fatal error - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". How can i output this thing?

Comment: Hmm... That seems to be an array. I'm not sure about overrides in PHP, but, you should have a file containing the `stdClass` class. Find that in your code, and search for a method that returns a string, or integer.

The line that may look like this: `echo $class[0];`

Should probably look like this: `echo $class[0].print();`

Comment: Object in Array :)
This one does it for me: $class[0]->name